# "no return tag error" despite correct tagging?

Tags: google-search-console, rel-alternate, canonical-url

I structured my website following [this tutorial](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2010/09/unifying-content-under-multilingual.html) that explains to do the following when you deal with profile pages that have menus translated but their contents are probably in the language of the content owner.

Example: Pedro is a Spanish guy. His profile on the **Spanish** version of the website will be the **canonical url** that lists all other variants like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example/en/profile/pedro" hreflang="en">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example/fr/profile/pedro" hreflang="fr">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example/it/profile/pedro" hreflang="it">
```

Those siblings will **not** have any alternate tags but only a **canonical** tag that links to the canonical URL (ie: Pedro's profile on the Spanish version of the page).

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/es/profile/pedro">
```

My questions:

1. Is this procedure (still) correct?
2. Why does Google Webmaster tools claim "no return tag" Error **in the thousands** when I do it like this?

You can see a real example here:

https://www.bodalgo.com/de/sprecher/armin-hierstetter

This is the canonical page that incorporates all the alternate languages which - in return - have the link above set as canonical. I do not understand why Webmaster Tools claim there needs to be a return tag when google's own tutorial (the link above) claims that there should not be any return tags on the non canonical language variant pages.